# Regex JQuery Find Elements By Type

Tags: jquery, regex

I´ve been trying to find elements by type for example radio,text and etc

I tried this code by Jquery:

```
$j("input[type^='text']").each(function(){
            alert($j(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The code above works properly, but I would like to find like this:

```
$j("input[type='text'|'radio']").each(function(){
            alert($j(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Is it possible? I am stucked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$j("input[type='text'],input[type='radio']").each(function(){
         alert($j(this).attr("id"));
});
```

You can also use `:text` and `:radio` selectors:

```
$j("input:text,input:radio").each(function(){
         alert($j(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: *"You can also use :text and :radio selectors:"* You *can*, but you *shouldn't*, for the reasons pointed out [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: isn't it safe to use with type like `input:text`??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Again, see the documentation. It forces jQuery to bypass the browser's own, built-in CSS engine, which is likely *dramatically* faster than jQuery's.